# What does "work backpack" for hand baggage mean?

Tags: luggage, airlines, italy

ITA Airways [hand baggage policy](https://www.ita-airways.com/en_it/fly-ita/baggage/hand-baggage.html) states :

> ITA SpA also lets you bring an accessory of your choice from the
> following:
>
> - Handbag
> - Work backpack
> - Laptop computer

I am confused about what does `work backpack` mean?

Comment: For me a backpack could be two somewhat different things - one would be a backpack that you might use to take things to school or work, the other would be a large backpack you'd take if going hiking for several days ([see here](https://www.switchbacktravel.com/best-backpacking-backpacks) ).  When I first read your question that is what I thought the distinction might be.

Comment: Yes, saying 'work backpack' when describing hand baggage means it isn't a large one that you'll use for hiking or camping. When I was a child, office workers and school children never used a backback, but a briefcase held in one hand. Now, they are a popular alternative. They are calling it an 'accessory'.

Comment: Sounds like a literal translation of "day pack" as opposed to a "hiking/tramping pack"

Comment: @Criggie There's some regional issues on that--I (Southwest US) routinely hike while wearing a day pack.  The division is between day packs and ones meant for a longer duration (bigger, to carry a tent/sleeping stuff/perhaps a bear canister.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I actually found found the [page](https://www.ita-airways.com/it_it/fly-ita/baggage/hand-baggage.html) in Italian which is way more helpful and it is in fact a translation issue and `work backpack` doesn't mean more than a normal backpack.

It is said :

> > In aggiunta ITA Airways ti consente di portare un accessorio a scelta tra i seguenti:
>
> - Zainetto
> - Borsetta
> - Pc portatile

Which is the same thing as above, with *Zainetto* meaning backpack and *Borsetta* meaning handbag

A drawing of the allowance is also present on that page

Comment: 45 x 36 x 20 is rather generous -- it's the same as easyJet. 40 x 30 is more typical. OTOH the primary 55 x 35 x 25 is unusually stingy. [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xM0I9Zi3hOsn3NTfkx9RE32qXgj1e3qHxuzvXfg2_78/edit#gid=0).